# INotifyPropertyChanged with a property that's a class?

Tags: c#, winforms

If I register to be notified of a property's change, it will only notify when the actual property is reassigned. So if I have a property that's a textbox, it won't notify if the text of the textbox changes, right? Is there any way to make it work this way?

Comment: If the class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` itself you can subscribe to the proper event.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in specific properties of an object then you should be using a mechanism like `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the value itself.  Unfortunately though in this case `TextBox` from WinForms doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  In order to listen for changes to its `Text` property you need to subscribe to the `TextChanged` event

Answer (score 0):

I have had a hard time imagining why a class would expose a property of type `TextBox`. Anyhow if you have ended up with such a design, you could simply add two properties, each for the `TextBox` itself and the text inside and then listen to `TextBox`'s `TextChanged` event and fire your `NotifyPropertyChanged` thereupon.

I do feel however that you need to rethink your approach. If your class exposes a property of `TextBox` type, there should really be places where you actually assign a new TextBox to a class instance and upper layers listening to this change. I don't think that would be the case however. You'd almost certainly be looking for text changes and should therefore expose a property of type `string`.

Comment: I see. So I would have a textbox in a class, listen to TextChanged events and then update a string property? That would be a more logical approach.